# Dark mode для сайта HTML

Tags: html

Всем привет! У меня есть следующий скрипт для моего сайта, он позволяет при нажатии на картинку ставить
дарк мод на сайте, то есть темный режим, и он работает как нужно:

```
let moon = document.getElementById("moonA");

moon.onclick = function () {
    let theme = document.getElementById("glownystyle");
    let photo = document.getElementById("moon");
    if (photo.getAttribute("src") == "sun.svg") {
        theme.href = "sunStyle.css";
        photo.src = "moon.svg";
    } else {
        theme.href = "moonStyle.css";
        photo.src = "sun.svg";
    }

    localStorage.theme = theme.getAttribute("href") == "sunStyle.css" || "moonStyle.css"
}
```

Но есть одна проблема, когда я обновляю страницу или перехожу на другую на моем сайте, то по умолчанию опять
ставится светлый режим, то есть браузер на запоминает того, что я применил в последний раз,
и я дописываю следующую строчку в моей функции:
' localStorage.theme = theme.getAttribute("href") == "sunStyle.css" || "moonStyle.css" '
и оно по идеи должно было бы уже запоминать, но не работает, может кто то знает как поправить код?
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Как раз этого я и не понимаю, как и сказал выше, у меня работает просто переключение а не запоминание тем

Comment: А как правильно записать их?

Comment: Что у вас значат 'mode' 'dark'?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122695/discussion-between-indevx-and-).